# Как скорректировать работу sphinx?

Tags: php, sphinx, sphinxsearch

Есть таблица по которой идет поиск с помощью sphinx

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В первой строке у нас фраза: **Big deal, Russian**
Во второй: **Russian, Big deal**
Я хочу чтобы поиск искал по словам и фразам разделенным запятой, то есть Слово Russian и фраза Big deal не должны взаимодействовать никак между собой.
При вводе запросе: **Russian Big deal** , я получаю что вторая категория получает больший вес, а при  запросе  **Big deal Russian** первая категория имеет больший вес. А по итогу я должен получить одинаковые веса.
Для поиска использую режим SPH_MATCH_ANY
Как настроить поиск чтобы он работал как мне нужно?

Answer (score 0):

Если вы не меняете режим ранжирования (через SetRankingMode() или OPTION ranker=...), то по умолчанию используется режим SPH_RANK_PROXIMITY_BM25, он в том числе учитывает LCS (longest common subsequence), что и влияет на разницу весов в вашем запросе на указанных документах. Попробуйте просто BM25 через SetRankingMode(SPH_RANK_BM25) или в SphinxQL - option ranker=bm25